# Реализовать функцию которая будет определять является ли строка палиндромом ? c# string

Tags: c#

я сделал таким способом , но может кто то знает вариант по проще

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите строку : ");
            String sl = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] sym = sl.ToCharArray();
            if (IsPalindrom(sym))
                Console.WriteLine("Палиндром");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Не палиндром");
        }
        static bool IsPalindrom(char[] word)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length / 2; i++)
                if (word[i] != word[word.Length - 1 - i])
            return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: как определяешь простоту варианта?

Comment: Мне его трудно понять, а другие я не нахожу. Думаю что есть проще к пониманию, но может я и ошибаюсь

Comment: Хорошее решение, только преобразование в `char[]` лишнее, так как сама строка это и есть массив символов, неизменяемый правда, но вам и не надо изменять. Попробуйте упростить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я обычно поясняю себе палиндром - это такая строка, где 2 одинаковые строки сходятся в центре.

То есть что то типа

```
В А С Я -> <- Я С А В
```

Есть еще второй вариант, когда 2 строки сходятся к нечетному символу

```
В А С Я -> О <- Я С А В
```

В обоих случаях, можно начать с концов и убирать по одной букве, пока не дойдем до середины, ну что то типа

```
В А С Я -> О <- Я С А В
  А С Я -> О <- Я С А
    С Я -> О <- Я С
      Я -> О <- Я
        -> О <-
```

Когда дойдем до момента, что остаётся 0 или 1 символ, то можно считать, что ответ найден.

Ну с такого пояснения, можно написать не самый короткий, зато очень понятный код

```
static bool IsPalindrom(string word)
{
    var left = 0;
    var right = word.Length - 1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        if (word[left] != word[right]) return false;
        left++;
        right--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

По сути, он делает абсолютно то же самое, что и ваш код, но просто по мне, так он читается полегче.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138409/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------).